# MySQL - Need help to figure out multiple joins

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using the following query to get the transactions from a table made to and from a user. I then want to retrieve the username for the sender_id and for the recipient_id. However I can only seem to get it for the recipient_id or the sender_id. Anyone have any ideas how I can get both.

```
SELECT us.name, ta.amount, ta.recipient_id, ta.sender_id, ta.timestamp_insert
        FROM  `transactions` AS ta
        JOIN users AS us
        ON ta.recipient_id=us.u_id
        WHERE ta.sender_id =111111 OR ta.recipient_id = 111111
        LIMIT 0 , 10
```

**Transactions Table Columns:**

transaction_id
tw_id
tw
sender_id
recipient_id
amount
timestamp_insert
timestamp_start 
timestamp_complete
transaction_status

**User Table Columns:**

u_id, 
name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to join twice, thus:

```
SELECT ta.amount, ta.recipient_id, ta.sender_id, ta.timestamp_insert, sender.name as Sender, recipient.name as Recipient
        FROM  `transactions` AS ta
        JOIN users AS recipient
        ON ta.recipient_id=recipient.u_id
        JOIN users AS sender
        ON ta.sender_id=sender.u_id
        WHERE ta.sender_id =111111 OR ta.recipient_id = 111111
        LIMIT 0 , 10
```